# SSRS: The content of the tabix doesn't go to next page although page breaks have been added

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, page-break

I have problem with SSRS 2008

My rdl file can be downloaded from: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qsvreevwfnb5n1w/rep10studentyearlyreport_new.rdl?dl=0

My problem is that even after I set Add a page break before for table of 'Student Enrichment Programme', when I export to pdf file, the content of Student Enrichment Programme doesn't start at new page. Please take a look at the picture belows:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/i3jvdwmmhoaexa7/pdfFile.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

try on the report on Tablix Properties

```
To add a page break to a data region

        1   On the design surface, right-click the corner handle of data region and then click Tablix Properties.

        2   On the General tab, under Page break options, select one of the following options:

                    - Add a page break before. Select this option when you want to add a page break before the table.

                    - Add a page break after. Select this option when you want to add a page break after the table.

                    - Fit table on one page if possible. Select this option when you want the data to stay on one page.
```

On the design surface, right-click the corner handle of data region and then click Tablix Properties.

[image]
[image]After that On the General tab, under Page break options, select one of the following options

SET On Tablix Properties Under PageBreak Set Breaklocation = Start

[image]

![enter image description here][4]

Comment: Hi Nayak, I did the same thing with you but the problem is that my tablix content doesn't go to a new page.

Comment: Sorry Nayak, Maybe my case is quite tricky. It still not go to the next page. Do you mind opening my rdl file for checking?

Comment: @user1979164 Hay i see your report you set your tablix properties BreakLocation = Start and KeepTogether = false :)

Comment: Hi Nayak. Do you mean that we have to set Keep Together = True to make it start at the new page? But here even after I set it to be True, it still doesn't start at new page.

Comment: @user1979164 I mean Set KeepTogether = false not True

Comment: Hi Nayak, please help. I have already set BreakLocation as Start, check the check box of "Add a page break before" and Keep together = False, but the content still doesn't go to a new page.